# Kernel Panic Dell Computer

Tags: boot, kernel, 22.04, uefi

My grandfather is an engineer and has ran ubuntu on many of his computers for years. He found this computer and recrafted it with 8RAM, an amazing battery, and got it to run Ubuntu. I have had it for about a year and was using it for about 2 months and then got busy and didn't go on it again. When I went to go on the computer again to go through the virtual box and run Acid Pro, after loading the Dell logo, it shows this:

```
*error hd0 disk gpt3 not found, click any key to continue*
```

I click enter and it says:

```
0.294780] /dev/root: Cant open blockdev

0.297696] Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block (0,0)

0.297717] CPU: 3 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 6.2.0-26-generic #26~22.04.1-Ubuntu

0.297737] Hardware name: Dell Inc. Precision M4800/0V5GVY, BIOS A26 06/13/2019

0.297755] Call Trace:

0.297762] <TASK>

0.297769] dump_stack_lvl+0x48/0x70

0.297782] dump_stack+0x10/0x20

0.297792] panic+0x35a/0x3a0

0.297804] mount_block_root+0x27b/0x280

0.297817] mount_root+0x83/0xb0

0.297826] prepare_namespace+oxf5/0x200

0.297837] kernel_init_freeable+0x*1c1/0x200

0.297849] ? __pfx_kernel_init+0x10/0x10

0.297861] kernel_init+0x1b/0x200

0.297871] ? __pfx_kernel_init+0x10/0x10

0.297882] ret_from_fork+0x2c/0x50

0.297893] </TASK>

0.298163] Kernel Offset: 0x2000000 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff80000000-0xffffffffbfffffff)

0.298195] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0) ]---
```

I have gone to the GNU Grub menu by clicking escape until it loads which from there I do not know what to do. I have also clicked f2 and that takes me to setup, where I do not want to click around much as I am not sure what I am doing at all.

I then found to click f12 which takes me to the one time boot menu. There is shows me that my Boot mode is set to UEFI with secure boot on. Which I found in the GNU grub menu it would not allow me to input any commands due to secure boot being on, however I know my grandfather put that on there for a reason so I do not want to change anything unless I know for sure that will fix the problem.
In the boot menu it gives me these options:

```
**UEFI BOOT:

ubuntu

windows boot manager

UEFI: WD Blue SA510 2.5 1000GB

OTHER OPTIONS:

BIOS Setup

BIOS Flash Update

Diagnostics

Change Boot Mode Settings**
```

I would have my grandfather help me but he is now in hospice and I do not want to press him on this because it is not the most crucial thing right now. I have done lots of research looking at various Linux websites, reddit posts, ubuntu formus, and even Dell itself but nothing seems to work.

I am assuming it has to do with it not having the flash drive with it to access the Operating System for Ubuntu, i vaguely remember him having on when setting it up. The issue with that is he has over 2 dozen different flash drives and I do not remember which one it was, and considering the cirumstances I don't want to ask him because if it is wrong due to memory, I dont want to accidently mess up the computer by plugging the wrong one into it.

Is there any way to fix the inability to boot due to the kernel panic? What can I do here? I have never used computers or know how to code but I am really determined to get this to work. Any help please, I am even considering downloading ubuntu on the computer I am using now, but I don't want to lose the other one because there was so much work that he put into it and it is very important. Could I take the computer in to someone and they be able to fix it possibly? Please help!

Thank youuuuuuuuuuuu! :) :(

ps. for some reason # 297762 and # 297893 wont appear but is says: task, all caps, in between <>

Comment: Have you checked your hardware health?  particularly drive  health given lines 1-3 of your pasted details?  (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools) though even good components *misbehave* if fed poor power; so I use any *issue* as a reason to check my hardware. In your case I'd have stopped trying to boot the system & performed basic hardware checks (*using live media & not your installed OS*); did you do anything like that?  Your mention of `virtualbox` has me confused, are you running this *on metal* or *virtual* (VM)?

Comment: Hi Guiverc, thank you for your response. I have not checked the hardware health, do you know how I would go about doing that? And in regards to the virtual box that really doesn't have much to do with the computer not being able to get past the kernel panic, i just mentioned it because it is apart of the way he set it up but i think that was inside of ubuntu and not to do with the "outside" of it. If that makes any sense?